# How can I navigate through errors after compilation in `latex-mode`?

Tags: latex

What I mean by debugging is the ability to navigate through errors after compilation.

I read that this can be done in AUCTeX with the command `C-c [backtick]`.  I was wondering if there was a similar command in the major latex mode from `latex-mode.el`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `next-error` and `previous-error` commands. By default
`next-error` is bound to all of `C-x [backtick]` (note this the `x`
instead of `c`), `M-g n` and `M-g M-n`; and `previous-error` is bound
to `M-g p` and `M-g M-p`. Out of these my favorites are `M-g M-n` and
`M-g M-p`.

By the way, all of those keybindings [1] also work with AucTeX (in
addition to the AucTeX specific `C-c [backtick]` you mentioned). More
generally, major modes are supposed to arrange for those same commands
to work with whatever kind of "error" messages you might have to deal
with in that mode. I put "error" in quotes because, for example, they
also work with `grep` or with `occur` to navigate between occurrences
of the search pattern. Definitely keybindings worth learning!

---

[1] AucTeX rebinds them to `TeX-next-error` and `TeX-previous-error`,
instead of using the standard `next-error` and `previous-error`, but
that's just a technicality.